# Importing Virtualbox to vsphere 6

Tags: vmware-vsphere, virtualbox, import, ovf

I have exported my virtualbox vm (ovf 1.0) and ran the ovf tool:

```
.\ovftool.exe --lax 'C:\users\perryg\desktop\old dev box\old dev box.ova' 
'C:\users\perryg\desktop\old dev box\old dev box.ovf'
```

That completes successfully. I then went into the ovf file and changed the virtualbox2.2 value to vmx07.

After attempting to import, I receive the following error message:

[PIIX4 of ResourceSubType element not found in []](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3uIB.png)

When I remove the items from the ovf file, the import does not work correctly. It eventually says no operating system found during the boot process.

What can I do from here?/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is probably to just use the VMware vCenter Converter, and treat your Virtualbox guest as if it were a physical machine.